# They took turns to shower/showering

Tags: word-choice

> They took turns *to shower/showering,* then got into bed.

Which more natural here? To shower or showering?

Comment: See [this NGram usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+turns+to+sit%2Ctook+turns+sitting%2Cit+in+turns+to+sit%2Cit+in+turns+sitting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20turns%20to%20sit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20turns%20sitting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20in%20turns%20to%20sit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20in%20turns%20sitting%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctook%20turns%20to%20sit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20turns%20sitting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20in%20turns%20to%20sit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20in%20turns%20sitting%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...showing we normally use the continuous participle in the construction *to take turns **doing** [something]*, but we prefer the infinitive in the common alternative construction *to take **it in turns to do** [it].* Note - that alternative version sometimes features singular *...take it in **turn** to do something*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"They took turns showering" is the most natural but I have no citation to prove it - only my long experience.

Answer (score 1):

Both "they take turns **showering**" and "they take turns **to shower**" are [correct](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/take-turns-to-verb-ing.3593541/). And the [NGram Chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took%20turns%20showering%2Ctook%20turns%20to%20shower&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) suggests that "take turns **showering**" is more natural.

Also see (every results show that take turns **v-ing** is used more frequently):

[Take turns sitting vs take turns to sit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20turns%20sitting%2C%20take%20turns%20to%20sit&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20sitting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20to%20sit%3B%2Cc0)

[Take turns singing vs take turns to sing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20turns%20singing%2Ctake%20turns%20to%20sing&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20singing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20to%20sing%3B%2Cc0)

[Take turns sleeping vs take turns to sleep](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+turns+sleeping%2Ctake+turns+to+sleep&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20sleeping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20sleeping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20turns%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0)